# SQL: NOLOCK causes query slow down

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any reason why adding a nolock to a query would cause it to increase execution time?

```
UPDATE TargetTable
      SET col1 = c1.RowCnt,
      col2 = c2.RowCnt
    from TargetTable tt
    join 
    (
      select col3, RowCnt = NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) from Table2 (nolock)
      group by col3
    ) c1 on c1.col3 = tt.ID 
    join
    (
      select col4, RowCnt = NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) from Table2 (nolock) 
      group by col4
    ) c2 on c2.col4 = tt.ID 

      WHERE timestamp BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
      AND (tt.Client_ID = @Client_ID)
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the time difference and how many rows are returned?

Comment: What do the query plans look like please? And what if you change this to a SELECT to test this bit?

Comment: Wouldn't this be risking updating to inaccurate data?

Comment: @HLGEM yes and no. The data shouldn't be modified/in use by anything by the time this query is run, but that makes me think about why he added nolock to them. He said the query was locking rows blocking other queries. Maybe it escalated the lock to table level...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOLOCK hint allows [Allocation Order Scans](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/11/09/when-can-allocation-order-scans-be-used.aspx). As such, they may create a completely different execution plan, one expected to be faster but that it turns out to be slower (eg. wrong cardinality estimates due to stale stats). As with any performance pro0blem, use an investigation methodology to find the cause of the problem. [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) is an excellent such methodology.

Comment: @JNK: Possible. Comparing estimated row count vs. actual row count in the actual plan will tell immediately if is bad stats.

Comment: unless it is an issue with selectivity on an index...had that issue recently on a clustered index with completely rebuild stats, b/c there were only 90k values for 500m+ rows. :)  Though I guess you can call that "incomplete" stats instead of "inaccurate" which would still be "bad" as you say.

Comment: We could speculate all day :) Point is, is better to measure and the Waits and Queues methodology is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 1):

Is this table under a lot of write activity? Are you sure that the right rows are affected in both cases? Have you tried using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL instead of putting individual hints within the query?

```
UPDATE tt SET 
    col1 = NULLIF(c1.RowCnt, 0),
    col2 = NULLIF(c2.RowCnt, 0)
FROM dbo.TargetTable AS tt
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT col3, RowCnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Table2 WITH (NOLOCK)
        GROUP BY col3
) AS c1 ON c1.col3 = tt.ID 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT col4, RowCnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Table2 WITH (NOLOCK)
        GROUP BY col4
) AS c2 ON c2.col4 = tt.ID 
WHERE tt.[timestamp] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
AND tt.Client_ID = @Client_ID;


-- with SQL Server's UPDATE FROM syntax, you should reference the alias in the UPDATE
-- use WITH (NOLOCK), as your current syntax could become an alias in later versions
-- get in the habit of using dbo. prefix and statement terminators
-- are you sure you don't want left joins?
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have ever heard.  I would look at:
- Changes is the data in the tables changing the overall cost of the query
- Other server activity locking the table being updated
- Other server activity lowering CPU availability
- Background OS tasks using Hard-Disk